# passing variables in redirect_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rails application, in `routes.rb` I have

```
match "show_fail" => "Posts#show_fail"
```

In `posts_controller.rb`:

```
def create
  ...
  return redirect_to show_fail_path, :title => @post.title
end

def show_fail
end
```

In `show_fail.html.erb`:

```
Unsuccessful posting of post title <%= title %>
```

But I got an error `undefined local variable or method 'title'`. Why does it not know about the `title` variable, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

redirect_to show_fail_path(:title => @post.title)

and take it from params[:title]